# Overlapping VideoViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview, overlap, z-order

.

Hi folks,

I have been trying to do this for days now and it's driving me crazy.

I have two layouts each containing a VideoView. Both of them are in a LinearLayout. They are displayed fine but when I move them (with an onTouchListener) the same one (last one added to the LinearLayout) is always on top, even if I use setZOrderOnTop(true) to the VideoView.

I tried all the methods to display videos I found on the internet but none seem to do the trick.

I also tried using a SurfaceView without success.

The code is fairly simple so there isn't really a need to post it, unless you ask for it.

Anyone got a clue?

Tom

[image: Weird overlapping videoviews]